# Schur Complement and Schur Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question, schur-complement, schur-decomposition

What is the relationship between Schur's decomposition and complement? Did Schur discover them together /  are they used in tandem for anything?

Comment: This is a good question. It is unfortunate no one has answered it (I don't know the answer myself either).